# Curl Not Starting

Tags: php, curl

This is my error

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so' - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: libssh2_knownhost_init in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so' - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: libssh2_knownhost_init in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
```

Comment: Update your `libcurl` and `libssh2` packages.

Comment: seem not be able to find that file

Comment: The first two error messages means the version of `libssh2` is older than the one `libcurl` requires. So if you're up to date on both, then you'll have to downgrade `libcurl` to one that matches the version of `libssh2`. The third error message means you're missing a required library for `ssh2.so`. You can use `ldd` to check which library you need.